# Как получить доступ к элементу через this

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ребята у меня такой html:

```
<div class="panelHNavElement">
      <div style="float:left;">Образование</div>
      <div style="float:right; margin-top:2px;"><img class="sparrow" src="/images/arrow-d.svg" height="14px"></div>
    </div>
```

Обрабатываю его так:

$(".panelHNavElement").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().children("div.panelHNavElementSpoilerBody").slideToggle("normal");
   return false;
  });

Скажите, как я могу при нажатии доступиться к элементу , я бы хотел ему изменить атрибут src. В данный момент представленный мною код работает на открытие спойлера. После

```
$(this).parent().children("div.panelHNavElementSpoilerBody").slideToggle("normal");
```

я хочу получить доступ к элементу картинки и там изменить атрибут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".panelHNavElement").click(function(){
  if ($(this).find('img.sparrow').attr('src') == '2.jpg') {
    $(this).find('img.sparrow').attr('src', '1.jpg'); //меняет src
  } else {
    $(this).find('img.sparrow').attr('src', '2.jpg'); //меняет src  
  }
  console.log($('img').attr('src')); //покажет новый src
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panelHNavElement">
      <div style="float:left;">Образование</div>
      <div style="float:right; margin-top:2px;"><img class="sparrow" src="1.jpg" height="14px"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: простите, а как можно дописать код что бы при втором нажатии на panelHNavElement вернуть src обратно в тот что был?

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое